# gfortran make error: "- recompile with -fPIC"

Tags: 16.04, make, compiler

I am encountering an error when compiling a fortran program: since I have a makefile provided, I open the working directory in the terminal and type `make`. Unfortunately I get this error:

```
relocation R_X86_64_32S against `.rodata.str1.1' can not be used when making a shared object; recompile with -fPIC
/usr/bin/ld: final link failed: Nonrepresentable section on output
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
makefile:43: recipe for target '<name>' failed
```

Actually I don't get how to "recompile with -fPIC".
I've tried typing `make -fPIC` and adding something like:

> CFLAGS = -fPIC
>   CXXFLAGS = -fPIC

to the makefile, but both haven't worked.
Any help is appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Google https://www.google.com/webhp?hl=all&gws_rd=ssl#hl=en&q=rodata.str1.1 → → http://jaytaylor.com/blog/2010/10/06/howto-fix-fpic-errors/

Comment: Doesn't work:  'bash: export: `-fPIC': not a valid identifier'

Comment: (1) the `not a valid identifier` error suggests you didn't quote the argument properly (2) since your are using fortran it probably needs to be more like `export FC="gfortran -fPIC"` but the details may depend on the Makefile - if you want more specific help then share the Makefile (and details about the program, if you can).